# Adding AlertDialog makes function not work [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to add an AlertDialog to confirm a save. But with this alertdialog it somehow doesn't work anymore and always shows the last else function in savePin (PIN must be 4 digits). When I remove the AlertDialog and just execute the savePin in the saveBtn it works just fine. No errors show up in the logcat. This is the dialog on saveBtn:

```
saveBtn!!.setOnClickListener{
        // Create popup dialog
        val saveDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        saveDialog.setTitle("Warning")
        saveDialog.setMessage("Confirm save")
        saveDialog.setPositiveButton("SAVE"){ _, _ -> savePin()}
        saveDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL") { _, _ -> }
        saveDialog.setCancelable(false)
        saveDialog.show()
    }
```

This is the savePin code:

```
private fun savePin() {
    if(editPinCode!!.text.toString() < 4.toString()){
        if(editPinCode!!.text.toString() == "0000"){
            Toast.makeText(this, "PIN cannot be 0000", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            if(editPinCode!!.text.isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter new PIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else{
                val pin = sharedPin.edit()
                pin.putString("pin", editPinCode!!.text.toString())
                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully saved PIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                pin.apply()
            }
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"PIN must be 4 digits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Any idea's on why it always goes to the "PIN must be 4 digits"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some weird condition to check length .that is what causing it ..

```
if(editPinCode!!.text.toString() < 4.toString())
```

If you are checking length it should be .

```
if(editPinCode!!.text?.length >= 4)
```

Comment: It still ends up going to the else ("PIN must be 4 digits"). Also the .length needs non-null asserted (!!) call, but with that it still doesn't work..

Comment: if `editPinCode` indeed is the Edttext you are using to enter PIN this should work . try to debug your code .. With the give code in question its not possible to find a cause for it .. Debug the value u are getting for `editPinCode!!.text!!.length`

Comment: You need to compare using less or equal to 4. Your code will look like this `if(editPinCode!!.text?.length <= 4)`

Comment: @masterturner96 i fixed the condition .. i was bit out of context before or just exhausted  i guess Sorry about that ..

Comment: Thanks, with the >= it is now working correctly